# puppet 3 add manifest directory in config instead file

Tags: config, manifest, puppet

I'm stuck and can't find any answer in google.
At now my master config point to single manifest
**manifest  = $confdir/manifests/cronjob.pp**
Question is how can i change point to directory instead to use all of the files(manifests) from this folder.
It's pretty annoying change point every time then you created new manifest.
I'm using puppet 3.24(and i now it's veeery old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer can be found by searching the [Puppet Configuration Reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#manifest)

Excerpt follows:

`The entry-point manifest for puppet master. This can be one file or a directory of manifests to be evaluated in alphabetical order. Puppet manages this path as a directory if one exists or if the path ends with a / or .`

This being said, if you set your `manifest` to the following:

`manifest = $confdir/manifests/`

It should read each `manifest` in the directory in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hello ptierno. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @stevemayster your welcome. If you feel this is the correct answer, please accept it as the answer.